# What are the predefined accounts (ALICE, BOB, etc)?

Tags: blockchain, account

When creating a blockchain node, I noticed that there are predefined accounts with a bunch of balances. Does everyone on my blockchain have access to these accounts? And how do I remove them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Balances pallet supports a Genesis Configuration which allows you to specify a set of accounts and balances that should exist at the genesis of your chain.

For a developer chain (using `--dev`), most nodes are configured to give genesis balances to a set of default accounts like `Alice`, `Bob`, `Charlie`, `Dave`, `Eve`, and `Ferdie`.

These accounts are all "well known" and has a documented private key:

```
bottom drive obey lake curtain smoke basket hold race lonely fit walk
```

So if you want to generate the private key pair for `Alice`, you would would add `//Alice` as a hard derivation key to the seed above:

```
bottom drive obey lake curtain smoke basket hold race lonely fit walk//Alice
```

To remove these genesis balances from your developer chain, you can modify the `testnet_genesis` in your project, however note that without genesis balances to any of your users, your chain may become locked out, since no one will be able to submit transactions without paying fees.

Answer (score 5):

In `node/src/chain_spec.rs` you will find the functions `local_testnet_config`
and `development_config` which contains lines like these

```
move || {
        testnet_genesis(
            wasm_binary,
            // Initial PoA authorities
            vec![authority_keys_from_seed("Alice"), authority_keys_from_seed("Bob")],
            // Sudo account
            get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice"),
            // Pre-funded accounts
            vec![
                get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice"),
                get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Bob"),
                get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Charlie"),
                get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Dave"),
                get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Eve"),
                get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Ferdie"),
                get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice//stash"),
                get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Bob//stash"),
                get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Charlie//stash"),
                get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Dave//stash"),
                get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Eve//stash"),
                get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Ferdie//stash"),
            ],
            true,
        )
    },
```

Modify this file to create the preseeded and sudo keys you want to use

To get the private keys for //Alice and //Bob it is possible to use `subkey` command

```
subkey inspect //Alice
```

and it returns:

```
Secret Key URI `//Alice` is account:
  Secret seed:       0xe5be9a5092b81bca64be81d212e7f2f9eba183bb7a90954f7b76361f6edb5c0a
  Public key (hex):  0xd43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d
  Public key (SS58): 5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY
  Account ID:        0xd43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d
  SS58 Address:      5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).