# What does Alice polkadot account mean?

Tags: substrate-parachain-template, rococo, account

In the polkadot account there is a private key and a public key.

What does the predefined account "Alice" means? I mean in the pre defined account is "Alice" is the title of the account?

I am asking this question because in the substrate-parachian-template in the chain_sepc.rs, there is a lie of code:

get_account_id_from_seed::sr25519::Public("Alice").

I wanted to replace this pre defined alice account with my own account so should I use my public key here like:

get_account_id_from_seed::sr25519::Public("5FRBorJ8HL3PpWrN2vpQLHEZobdyvwirUcGmtB2WMhxJtToy")

Or I will use the title of my account like:
get_account_id_from_seed::sr25519::Public("SYED KAMRAN")

Answer (score 0):

This should be helpful:

- [What are the predefined accounts (ALICE, BOB, etc)?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/41/what-are-the-predefined-accounts-alice-bob-etc)

You would do something like this:

```rust
hex!["c02563505b8fc10f0acb3e97982d663424d4617baced9bcf51c847bd879ff827"].into()
```

You can use `subkey` to get the address from SS58.

- https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/8777/29