# How to add custom account as initial authorities in chain_spec.rs file

Tags: substrate-node-template, polkadot, substrate-node, account, polkadot-local

I've successfully added custom accounts in the Sudo account and pre-funded accounts following this stack  [adding an account](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/8775/adding-an-account/8777#8777)  but I also wanted to set custom accounts as initial PoA authorities.

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what permissions you need to give to the accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this tutorial https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-blockchain/authorize-specific-nodes/ to set initial authorities in the system.

Comment: hey @Shubham Gupta ,

can you please explain to us a little bit more about how we can achieve on adding a custom account as initial authorities.