# How to Recover Address from MasterPrivateKey in JS

Tags: polkadot-js, signing, address, ledger

I trying to make Signature using Polkadot.js without mnemonic in LedgerAddress.

```
import { hdLedger } from "@polkadot/util-crypto";
import { u8aToHex } from "@polkadot/util";
import Keyring from "@polkadot/keyring";
const keyring = new Keyring();
keyring.setSS58Format(0);
function getSuri(seed, derivePath, pairType) {
  return pairType === "ed25519-ledger"
    ? u8aToHex(hdLedger(seed, derivePath).secretKey.slice(0, 32))
    : pairType === "ethereum"
    ? `${seed}/${derivePath}`
    : `${seed}${derivePath}`;
}

function addressFromSeed(seed, derivePath, pairType) {
  return keyring.createFromUri(
    getSuri(seed, derivePath, pairType),
    {},
    pairType === "ed25519-ledger" ? "ed25519" : pairType
  ).address;
}
const Polkadot_Path = "m/44'/354'/0'/0/0";
const Phase =
  "tilt wise rent open chunk wheel tonight army meat virus rule catch hospital nurse verb pretty guide cook illegal spell honey obscure desk brick";
console.log("Target: ", addressFromSeed(Phase, Polkadot_Path, "ed25519-ledger"));
function hexStrToByteArr(hexStr) {
  hexStr = hexStr.replace(/ /g, "");

  if (hexStr.slice(0, 2).toLowerCase() === "0x") hexStr = hexStr.slice(2, hexStr.length);
  const bin = [];
  let i;
  let c;
  let isEmpty = 1;
  let buffer;
  for (i = 0; i < hexStr.length; i++) {
    c = hexStr.charCodeAt(i);
    if ((c > 47 && c < 58) || (c > 64 && c < 71) || (c > 96 && c < 103)) {
      buffer = (buffer << 4) ^ ((c > 64 ? c + 9 : c) & 15);
      if ((isEmpty ^= 1)) {
        bin.push(buffer & 0xff);
      }
    }
  }
  return bin;
}
const masterKey = "32fc49249c9d192d1c2aa94c629b4d6fb9deb80165e9a1844bfd3894724d5dee";
const masterToUint8 = new Uint8Array(hexStrToByteArr(masterKey));

const result = keyring.addFromSeed(masterToUint8);
console.log("result: ", result.address);
```

The master key was created using `PBKDF2` and `bip32.fromSeed`.

The problem is that the target log and result log are different. I don't understand why this is happening and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a little snippet as an example of how to recover the account from a mnemonic and a seed using Alice testing account. You can check the menmonic and seed for this account in this previous StackExchange question:  [What are the predefined accounts (ALICE, BOB, etc)?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/47/2762).

See below the snippet that works, it might help you to see why is not working in your particular case:

```js
    await cryptoWaitReady();
    const keyring = new Keyring({ type: 'sr25519' });

    const PHRASE = "bottom drive obey lake curtain smoke basket hold race lonely fit walk//Alice";
    const pairWithMnemonic = keyring.addFromUri(PHRASE);
    const pairWithSeeds = keyring.addFromUri('0xe5be9a5092b81bca64be81d212e7f2f9eba183bb7a90954f7b76361f6edb5c0a');
    
    console.log(pairWithMnemonic.address);
    console.log(pairWithSeeds.address);
```